# Issues with handling special characters when reading environment variables from python script

Tags: python, string, unix, environment-variables, config

I have setup environment variables for to access MongoDB database. All works except for the MongoDB connection string which is pretty long.

Mongodb string can be provided in different format,

```bash
mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/?authSource=admin
```

Other examples are here - https://www.fosslinux.com/50317/connection-string-in-mongodb-with-examples.htm

In my case the string was provided by the database admin, so I am using it as it is provided. All, the environmental variables are shown at it is in `.bashrc` file except the MONGODB connection string. If I use the string from within my python script it works well, but when I call it through environment variables (.bashrc file) something changes the string.

**Setup on .bashrc**

```bash
export MGDB_CON_STRING="mongodb://myMGDB:someuname....................server/dbname?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN....."
```

When this variable is called by python script as

```bash
mgdb_con_str = os.environ["MGDB_CON_STRING"]
```

something is eating up the text `$external&` to be exact) in this string and returning it as

```
"mongodb://myMGDB:someuname....................server/dbname?authSource=authMechanism=PLAIN....."
```

**However, if I override this variable again by using it within python script it works**

`mgdb_con_str = r"mongodb://myMGDB:someuname....................server/dbname?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN....."` **- so this works**

Something is eating that `$external&` within the string and I cannot find what exactly is causing this. I also cannot find any question related to this problem elsewhere on stack or general google search. But, string value of all other environment variables do not change. And, similar problem arises if I read the mongodb string through config file.

Comment: Nothin is "eating it up" - `$external` refers to *another* env variable, `$external` which is empty, that's why it is replaced with an empty string.

Comment: But, why would it not connect to my mongodb database then. When I override the same variable by capturing using breakpoint and continuing it work perfectly.

Comment: because `authSource` can't be empty? Ask your admin what it should be. This is unrelated to Python, at all

Comment: Well why is it able to make connection when I type it directly on python script? And if having “$external&” on python works the environment variable should not clip it. There should be a way to tell “os.environ()” to not clip it. Is there? This should be handled this way rather than asking admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One other way to handle this situation is to use single quotes when preparing the environment variables and it work bash and csh scripts.

Instead of this

```bash
export MGDB_CON_STRING="mongodb://myMGDB:someuname....................server/dbname?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN....."
```

Do this

```bash
export MGDB_CON_STRING='mongodb://myMGDB:someuname....................server/dbname?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN.....'
```

When this variable is called by python script as

```py
mgdb_con_str = os.environ["MGDB_CON_STRING"]
print(mgdb_con_str)
# returns the raw string
'mongodb://myMGDB:someuname....................server/dbname?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN.....'
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Python, just with how linux handles env variables.

When you are doing

```
export A="...authSource=$external&something_else"
```

`$external` is interpreted as the environment variable `$external`. Since it does not exist, it is replaced with an empty string:

```bash
bash-4.2$ export A="...authSource=$external&something_else"
bash-4.2$ echo $A
...authSource=&something_else
```

You need an actual `$` in your env variable value, so you need to escape it with `\`:

```bash
bash-4.2$ export A="...authSource=\$external&something_else"
bash-4.2$ echo $A
...authSource=$external&something_else
```

Of course assigning `mgdb_con_str = r"mongodb://myMGDB:someuname....................server/dbname?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN....."` directly in the Python script will work, since it does not try to evaluate env variables and `$external` is just the literal string `$external`.

Actual example:

```
bash-4.2$ export NO_ESCAPED="aa$aa&g"
bash-4.2$ export ESCAPED="aa\$aa&g"
bash-4.2$ echo $NO_ESCAPED
aa&g
bash-4.2$ echo $ESCAPED
aa$aa&g
bash-4.2$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('NO_ESCAPED')
'aa&g'
>>> os.getenv('ESCAPED')
'aa$aa&g'
```

Comment: @everestial007 you could also just use single quotes instead of double quotes, that will disable string substitution by the shell.